# Android LruCache in Android 1.6+

Tags: android, memorycache

I need to use LruCache (a api from Android 3.1) in Android 1.6+

I use Android Support Library v4 that has support to LruCache (Acording with this manual http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#memory-cache )
but the problem is that i get the NoClassDefNotFoundError all the time. I include the support.v4 library in my project (in other activity i use ViewPager... )

Anyone have a idea of why this happend?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To avoid the problem i included the LruClass.java in my own project and the NoClassDefNotFoundError not apear anymore

The LruClass.java is located in:

**Android sdk location /extras/android/support/v4/src/java/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.java**

Answer (score 12):

you need to use `android.support.v4.util.LruCache<K, V>` not `android.util.LruCache<K, V>` since second one only exists on android with API >= 12 ... check if imported the one from support library not from SDK ...

Comment: How i put, yes i include support.v4, not util. Anyway the problem happend in my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.4 too :S

The only solution that i find is take LruCache.java from the code of support library and put it in my project directly